# Animations not kicking-in ng-show/hide

Tags: angularjs, stylus

**Edit**

Added some classes, but I'm still missing something

```
$duration = .3s
.fade
  transition $duration linear all
  &.ng-enter
    opacity 0
    transition-delay $duration
    &-active
      opacity 1
  &-hide
    opacity 1
    &.ng-hide
      opacity 0
      transition-delay $duration

  &.ng-leave, &.ng-hide-remove
    opacity 1
    &-active
      opacity 0
```

It works now, but not in the right way

---

Let's say I have this simple animation

animation.stylus

```
$duration = .3s
.fade
  &.ng-enter
    transition $duration linear all
    opacity 0
    transition-delay $duration
    &-active
      opacity 1

  &.ng-leave
    transition $duration linear all
    opacity 1
    &-active
      opacity 0
```

animation.css

```
.fade.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.fade.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear all;
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

What am I missing? Because it works in ng-view, but doesn't in ng-show/hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work, ng-show (and ng-hide) need additional explicit css (or js) rules, here they are:

```
.fade
  &.ng-hide-add
    opacity 1
    &-active
      opacity 0
      display none
  &.ng-hide-remove
    opacity 0
    &-active
      opacity 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Done, didn't write a long answer because it's just that